# AWS Java SDK - using ProgressListener with TransferManager

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-java-sdk

I am looking at usage example provided in AWS SDK docs for [TransferManager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html?com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html), in particular for the following code:

```java
TransferManager tx = new TransferManager(
               credentialProviderChain.getCredentials());
Upload myUpload = tx.upload(myBucket, myFile.getName(), myFile);
 // Transfers also allow you to set a <code>ProgressListener</code> to receive
// asynchronous notifications about your transfer's progress.
myUpload.addProgressListener(myProgressListener);
```

and I am wondering whether we don't have here case of a race condition. AFAIU `TransferManager` works asynchronously, it may start the uploading file straight away after the `Upload` object creation, even before we add the listener, so if we use the snippet as provided in the docs, it seems to be possible that we won't receive all notifications. I've looked briefly into the `addProgressListener` and I don't see there that past events would be replayed on attaching a new listener. Am I wrong? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to get ALL events, I imagine this can be achieved using a different [`upload`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.html#upload-com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest-com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.internal.S3ProgressListener-) method that takes in a `ProgressListener` as a parameter.  Of course, using this method will require encapsulating your bucketname, key, and file into an instance of `PutObjectRequest`.

Comment: So I am kind of right? I've seen the method you linked and I am planning to use it. I am just trying to confirm my reasoning or figure out what I got wrong.

Comment: I would assume there are many situations where folks are primarily interested in knowing when their transfer has completed successfully, and are less interested in ensuring they get all of the events that a ProgressListener would support.  I just see this as an overloaded method to support different use cases.

Comment: In other words, you are probably correct about not necessarily getting all of the events, but the authors assume that it doesn't matter in most cases.

Comment: Oh that's ultimately my goal - learning in a non blocking fashion about upload completion - failure or success. Thought that progress listener is the way to go.